# My column disappears whenever screen goes medium in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frameworks

So I'm trying to make similar design as based on this website: https://www.rezydencjagubalowka.pl/en/ when presenting the rooms and I have one problem which is that the white columns I made (next to Lorem ipsum thing) are dissapearing whenever I resize my screen size to smaller. Here you can see the code:

```
<div class="pokaz">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row pt-5">
               <div class="col-lg-6 bg-white" style="text-align: center;">
                  <svg class="bi bi-gem mt-3" width="3em" height="3em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                     <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.1.7a.5.5 0 0 1 .4-.2h9a.5.5 0 0 1 .4.2l2.976 3.974c.149.185.156.45.01.644L8.4 15.3a.5.5 0 0 1-.8 0L.1 5.3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.6l3-4zm11.386 3.785l-1.806-2.41-.776 2.413 2.582-.003zm-3.633.004l.961-2.989H4.186l.963 2.995 5.704-.006zM5.47 5.495l5.062-.005L8 13.366 5.47 5.495zm-1.371-.999l-.78-2.422-1.818 2.425 2.598-.003zM1.499 5.5l2.92-.003 2.193 6.82L1.5 5.5zm7.889 6.817l2.194-6.828 2.929-.003-5.123 6.831z"/>
                  </svg>
                  <h1 class="font-weight-bold mt-2" style="color: #14747d;">Lorem ipsum</h1>
                  <h4 class="font-weight-lighter mt-4 text-break">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Czytaj więcej</button>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-6 bg-white">

            </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 bg-white">

                </div>
               <div class="col-lg-6 bg-white" style="text-align: center;">
                  <svg class="bi bi-gem mt-3" width="3em" height="3em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                     <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.1.7a.5.5 0 0 1 .4-.2h9a.5.5 0 0 1 .4.2l2.976 3.974c.149.185.156.45.01.644L8.4 15.3a.5.5 0 0 1-.8 0L.1 5.3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.6l3-4zm11.386 3.785l-1.806-2.41-.776 2.413 2.582-.003zm-3.633.004l.961-2.989H4.186l.963 2.995 5.704-.006zM5.47 5.495l5.062-.005L8 13.366 5.47 5.495zm-1.371-.999l-.78-2.422-1.818 2.425 2.598-.003zM1.499 5.5l2.92-.003 2.193 6.82L1.5 5.5zm7.889 6.817l2.194-6.828 2.929-.003-5.123 6.831z"/>
                  </svg>
                  <h1 class="font-weight-bold mt-2" style="color: #14747d;">Lorem ipsum</h1>
                  <h4 class="font-weight-lighter mt-4 text-break">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Czytaj więcej</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="container pb-5">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-6 bg-white" style="text-align: center;">
                  <svg class="bi bi-gem mt-3" width="3em" height="3em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                     <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.1.7a.5.5 0 0 1 .4-.2h9a.5.5 0 0 1 .4.2l2.976 3.974c.149.185.156.45.01.644L8.4 15.3a.5.5 0 0 1-.8 0L.1 5.3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.6l3-4zm11.386 3.785l-1.806-2.41-.776 2.413 2.582-.003zm-3.633.004l.961-2.989H4.186l.963 2.995 5.704-.006zM5.47 5.495l5.062-.005L8 13.366 5.47 5.495zm-1.371-.999l-.78-2.422-1.818 2.425 2.598-.003zM1.499 5.5l2.92-.003 2.193 6.82L1.5 5.5zm7.889 6.817l2.194-6.828 2.929-.003-5.123 6.831z"/>
                  </svg>
                  <h1 class="font-weight-bold mt-2" style="color: #14747d;">Lorem ipsum</h1>
                  <h4 class="font-weight-lighter mt-4 text-break">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Czytaj więcej</button>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-6 bg-white">

               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Is anyone willing to help? I will include link to codepen in comments

Comment: https://codepen.io/bial654321/pen/rNxjvEX

Comment: Remove `height: 300px` from class `.break` as it limits the height of the container to 300px. There is simply more text than can fit in 300px.

Comment: Yeah I did that and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
**remove class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 bg-white" marked ?? area .its empty. thats why it dissepears**

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 bg-white">
            **??**
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-6 bg-white" style="text-align: center;">
            <svg class="bi bi-gem mt-3" width="3em" height="3em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
             <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.1.7a.5.5 0 0 1 .4-.2h9a.5.5 0 0 1 .4.2l2.976 3.974c.149.185.156.45.01.644L8.4 15.3a.5.5 0 0 1-.8 0L.1 5.3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.6l3-4zm11.386 3.785l-1.806-2.41-.776 2.413 2.582-.003zm-3.633.004l.961-2.989H4.186l.963 2.995 5.704-.006zM5.47 5.495l5.062-.005L8 13.366 5.47 5.495zm-1.371-.999l-.78-2.422-1.818 2.425 2.598-.003zM1.499 5.5l2.92-.003 2.193 6.82L1.5 5.5zm7.889 6.817l2.194-6.828 2.929-.003-5.123 6.831z"/>
                  </svg>
                  <h1 class="font-weight-bold mt-2" style="color: #14747d;">Lorem ipsum</h1>
                  <h4 class="font-weight-lighter mt-4 text-break">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Czytaj więcej</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="container pb-5">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-6 bg-white" style="text-align: center;">
                  <svg class="bi bi-gem mt-3" width="3em" height="3em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                     <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.1.7a.5.5 0 0 1 .4-.2h9a.5.5 0 0 1 .4.2l2.976 3.974c.149.185.156.45.01.644L8.4 15.3a.5.5 0 0 1-.8 0L.1 5.3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.6l3-4zm11.386 3.785l-1.806-2.41-.776 2.413 2.582-.003zm-3.633.004l.961-2.989H4.186l.963 2.995 5.704-.006zM5.47 5.495l5.062-.005L8 13.366 5.47 5.495zm-1.371-.999l-.78-2.422-1.818 2.425 2.598-.003zM1.499 5.5l2.92-.003 2.193 6.82L1.5 5.5zm7.889 6.817l2.194-6.828 2.929-.003-5.123 6.831z"/>
                  </svg>
                  <h1 class="font-weight-bold mt-2" style="color: #14747d;">Lorem ipsum</h1>
                  <h4 class="font-weight-lighter mt-4 text-break">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Czytaj więcej</button>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-6 bg-white">

               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: these columns were made to put image there instead of white space

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution. I just had to put

```
<div class="col-lg-6 p-0">
<img src="img/hotel-room.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
```

with a photo and "p-0" in the col's class name to make photo look cleaner